# I am getting an error in my Python code

Tags: python

Right now I'm doing a easy videogame in Python using the libraty Turtle but this error appeared and I don't know how to solve it.

My code is here:

pastebin.com/wu5jM0gT

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/ricar/PycharmProjects/Juego/Juego.py", line 122, in <module>
objetivo.movimiento()
File "C:/Users/ricar/PycharmProjects/Juego/Juego.py", line 91, in movimiento
self.forward(self.speed)
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\turtle.py", line 1553, in forward
self._go(distance)
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\turtle.py", line 1520, in _go
ende = self._position + self._orient * distance
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\turtle.py", line 277, in __mul__
return Vec2D(self[0]*other, self[1]*other)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'instancemethod'`
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `self.speed` a number? Please include your code in the question, formatted with the `{}` button, instead of as a link.

Comment: On line 91, you are passing `Turtle.speed` to the forward function. Since speed is an instance method of Turtle and not an expected numeric you get that error. You probably wanted `self.forward(self.speed())` calling speed with no argument returns the current speed as a number and then `forward` is happy.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the parentheses

```
self.forward(self.speed())
```

Comment: Thank you so much!